# Wrong depth buffer (to texture) output?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, depth-buffer, render-to-texture

For the SSAO effect I have to generate two textures: normals (in view space) and depth.

I decided to use depth buffer as texture according to [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx) (the *Reading the Depth-Stencil Buffer as a Texture* chapter).

Unfortunately, after rendering I got none information from the depth buffer (the lower image):

[image]

I guess it's not right. And what is strange, the depth buffer seems to work (I get the right order of faces etc.).

The depth buffer code:

```
//create depth stencil texture (depth buffer)
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = antiAliasing.getCount();
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = antiAliasing.getQuality();
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencil = NULL;
result = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &depthStencil);
ERROR_HANDLE(SUCCEEDED(result), L"Could not create depth stencil texture.", MOD_GRAPHIC);

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
//setup the description of the shader resource view
shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = antiAliasing.isOn() ? D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS : D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

//create the shader resource view.
ERROR_HANDLE(SUCCEEDED(device->CreateShaderResourceView(depthStencil, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &depthStencilShaderResourceView)),
    L"Could not create shader resource view for depth buffer.", MOD_GRAPHIC);

createDepthStencilStates();
//set the depth stencil state.
context->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState3D, 1);

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
// Initialize the depth stencil view.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

// Set up the depth stencil view description.
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = antiAliasing.isOn() ? D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS : D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
//depthStencilViewDesc.Flags = D3D11_DSV_READ_ONLY_DEPTH;

// Create the depth stencil view.
result = device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencil, &depthStencilViewDesc, &depthStencilView);
ERROR_HANDLE(SUCCEEDED(result), L"Could not create depth stencil view.", MOD_GRAPHIC);
```

After rendering with first pass, I set the depth stencil as texture resource along with other render targets (color, normals), appending it to array:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView ** textures = new ID3D11ShaderResourceView *[targets.size()+1];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++) {
    textures[i] = targets[i]->getShaderResourceView();
}
textures[targets.size()] = depthStencilShaderResourceView;
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, targets.size()+1, textures);
```

Before second pass I call `context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &myRenderTargetView, NULL);` to unbind depth buffer (so I can use it as texture).

Then, I render my textures (render targets from first pass + depth buffer) with trivial post-process shader, just for debug purpose (second pass):

```
Texture2D ColorTexture[3];
SamplerState ObjSamplerState;

float4 main(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET0{
    float4 Color;
    Color = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
    float2 textureCoordinates = input.textureCoordinates.xy * 2;
    if (input.textureCoordinates.x < 0.5f && input.textureCoordinates.y < 0.5f) {
        Color = ColorTexture[0].Sample(ObjSamplerState, textureCoordinates);
    }
    if (input.textureCoordinates.x > 0.5f && input.textureCoordinates.y < 0.5f) {
        textureCoordinates.x -= 0.5f;
        Color = ColorTexture[1].Sample(ObjSamplerState, textureCoordinates);
    }
    if (input.textureCoordinates.x < 0.5f && input.textureCoordinates.y > 0.5f) { //depth texture
        textureCoordinates.y -= 0.5f;
        Color = ColorTexture[2].Sample(ObjSamplerState, textureCoordinates);
    }
...
```

It works fine for normals texture. Why it doesn't for depth buffer (as shader resource view)?

Comment: Depth buffers will often look uniformly red when viewed because typically the values range between about 0.99 and 1 with improperly set near and far clip planes. Have you verified the data is wrong by anything other than visual inspectiom?

Comment: @AdamMiles you're right! After investigation, I've found that values are indeed between 0.999f and 1.000f. I set my far and near clip planes with `DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(DirectX::XM_PIDIV4, screenWidth / (FLOAT)screenHeight, 0.01f, 20000.0f);` Should I change them? the values like `0.01f, 200.0f` does **not** provide better values (in larger range) and additionally some of my geometry get's clipped. Is there anything else I could manipulate to get better results?

Comment: The values should as closely clamp the visible range of your scene as possible. A near clip value of 0.01 would suggest you don't want objects to clip out until they're 1cm from the camera, you could probably get away with at least 0.1 here. A far clip of 20000 suggests a draw distance of 20km (assuming metres are your units) which also seems excessive. Even at 0.1 / 200 chances are it will mostly still be > 0.9, but it's not a huge deal except for when you try to visualise the data as you have done. Perhaps re-scale 0.9-1 -> 0.0-1.0 when visualising it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments:

The texture was rendered and sampled correctly but the data appeared to be uniformly red due to the data lying between 0.999 and 1.0f.

There are a few things you can do to improve the available depth precision, but the simplest of which is to simply ensure your near and far clip distances are not excessively small/large for the scene you're drawing.

Assuming metres are your unit, a near clip of 0.1 (10cm) and a far clip of 200 (metres) are much more reasonable than 1cm and 20km.

Even so, don't expect to see too many black/dark areas, the non linear nature of a z-buffer is still going to mean most of your depth values are shunted up towards 1. If visualisation of the depth buffer is important then simply rescale the data to the normalised 0-1 range before displaying it.